# JQuery Deferred Ajax, save result in the calling object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, jquery-deferred

I'm pretty new to the whole prototype idea in Javascript, from what I've gathered so far it's basically a template for new objects to be created from.

Anyway, I have an object "Schedule" that is a child of "PageObject".
Here is a function from the Schedule object:

```
Schedule.prototype.serviceSuccessFunction = function(data, status, xqr) {
  var ld;
  ld = Schedule.__super__.serviceSuccessFunction.call(this, data, status, xqr);
  ld.done($.proxy(function(x) {
    return console.log(this);
  }, this));
  ld.done($.proxy(this.render, this));
  return ld.done($.proxy(this.modernizeAndShow, this));
};
```

And here is what the PageObject's function looks like (being called from it's child):

```
PageObject.prototype.serviceSuccessFunction = function(data, status, xqr) {
  $.mobile.loading("show");
  return $.when($.mobile.loadPage("pages/" + this.url, {
    pageContainer: $("#" + this.loadOptions.loadSection)
  }));
};
```

As you can see, the PageObject is returning the deferred object for when this mobile page loads.  I then have custom .done() functions in the Schedule object.  These done functions will render based on what the "data" parameter is.

This "data" parameter comes from another deferred object (using $.ajax).  When I breakpoint on the first line of the Schedule success function, "data" is properly filled in with what the ajax call returned.

Now my problem is I want to be able to call a different function in Schedule with the data as a parameter, or save the data on the Schedule object itself.  How do you suppose I would pass in the data object into these functions?

When I breakpoint on the `return console.log(this);` line, "this" is the Schedule object thanks to the $.proxy.  But I am unable to find "data" (which makes sense I suppose).  Ideally I would like to pass in "data" as a parameter and do something like

```
ld.done($.proxy(function(data) {
  this.rData = data;
}, this));
```

But "data" or "x" above is just the url of the .ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have misunderstood but can you not just place `this.rData = data;` outside the "done" function:

```
Schedule.prototype.serviceSuccessFunction = function(data, status, xqr) {
  var ld;
  ld = Schedule.__super__.serviceSuccessFunction.call(this, data, status, xqr);

  this.rData = data;

  ld.done($.proxy(function(x) {
    return console.log(this.rData);
  }, this));
  ld.done($.proxy(this.render, this));
  return ld.done($.proxy(this.modernizeAndShow, this));
};
```

The rData is then available inside your delegate.

Comment: Wow, durr.  This is what happens when you are tired and being too deep in to see the surface.